# I'm trying to get the ID from another csv file

Tags: python, pandas, list, arraylist, data-analysis

The csv files I read in

```
games = pd.read_csv("games.csv")
games_details = pd.read_csv("games_details.csv")
players = pd.read_csv("players.csv")
ranking = pd.read_csv("ranking.csv")
teams = pd.read_csv("teams.csv")
```

Here I got the games season that where greater than 2015 then I got the  season gameId only

```
season = games[games.SEASON > 2015]
gameID = season.GAME_ID
```

Here I'm trying to get the game ID from  games_details but i only want the id's that was stored in gameID but it's not returning anything

```
for i in gameID:
        detail = games_details[games_details.GAME_ID == i ]
    
    id = detail.GAME_ID
   
    print(id, "\t " ,gameid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isin function:

```
print(games_details[games_details['GAME_ID'].isin(gameID)].GAME_ID)
```